Nodemailer Sending Email hangs with a ETIMEDOUT and at Resolved but eventually sends email
So I have this one problem with an app I am building using Nodemailer to send email to an SMTP server (or gmail) and I am getting a weird problem.
TL;DR: The email does get sent but it's rare. Other times it just hangs at Resolved then eventually times out (I added a time out).
Here is a video of what the console is doing: Here
As you can see in the video, eventually the email gets sent. Then it times out.
I get an 'ETIMEDOUT' error on most of the times it attempts to send.
Not that it's needed but I'm sending an email by pushing a button on a site built with ReactJS. I also tried directly accessing the API function using Thunder Client. That has nothing to do with it.
Here is the transporter:
const createTransporter = (serviceSettings) => {
// Define which service to use
// gmail    = Use gmail's service (must have GmailSMTPUser and GmailSMTPAppPass setup)
// ll       = Use LumiereLabs's service
const emailService = serviceSettings.use
// Configure the transporter

switch (emailService) {
    case "gmail":
        return nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                user: serviceSettings.services.gmail.user,
                pass: serviceSettings.services.gmail.pass
            },
            logger: true,
            debug: true,
            maxConnections: 5, // Maximum number of connections to keep in the pool
            maxMessages: 100, // Maximum number of messages to send per connection
            rateLimit: 10, // Maximum number of messages to send per second
            pool: true, // disable connection pooling
            connectionTimeout: 10000,  // 10 seconds
            socketTimeout: 10000,      // 10 seconds
            greetingTimeout: 5000      // 5 seconds    
        })
    break

    case "ll":
        return nodemailer.createTransport({                    
            host: 'smtp.lumierelabs.org',
            port: 587,
            secure: false,       // true for 465, false for others
            requireTLS: true,
            auth: {
                user: serviceSettings.services.ll.user,
                pass: serviceSettings.services.ll.pass
            },
            tls: {
                rejectUnauthorized: false // if using self-signed certificates
            },
            logger: true,
            debug: true,
            maxConnections: 5, // Maximum number of connections to keep in the pool
            maxMessages: 100, // Maximum number of messages to send per connection
            rateLimit: 10, // Maximum number of messages to send per second
            pool: true, // disable connection pooling
            connectionTimeout: 10000,  // 10 seconds
            socketTimeout: 10000,      // 10 seconds
            greetingTimeout: 5000      // 5 seconds                
        })
    break
}

}
Here is the function I created to handle the email:
const sendEmail = async (mailOptions, successMessage, res, serviceSettings) => {
let toasts = []

const transporter = createTransporter(serviceSettings)
            
try {
    let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)

    // Send to notification
    toasts.push({ message: successMessage, object: { sentEmail: true }, type: 'success' })

    // Send to console
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response)
} catch (error) {
    // Send to notification
    toasts.push({ message: `Error sending mail: ${error}`, object: { sentEmail: false },  type: 'error'})

    // Send to console
    console.error('Error sending email: ', error)

    // Rethrow error to handle it upstream
    throw error
} finally {
    transporter.close() // close the connection pool

    // return something
    if(toasts.length > 0) {
        // Toasts found!
        // Check for type
        if (toasts[0].type === "error") {                                               
            // Error                                                                        
            if (!res.headersSent) {
                return res.status(400).json(toasts)
            } else {
                console.warn('Attempted to send a response after headers were already sent.');
            }                      
        } if (toasts[0].type === "unauthorized") {
            // Unauthorized
            if (!res.headersSent) {
                return res.status(401).json(toasts)
            } else {
                console.warn('Attempted to send a response after headers were already sent.');
            }                      
        } else {
            if (!res.headersSent) {
                return res.status(200).json(toasts)
            } else {
                console.warn('Attempted to send a response after headers were already sent.');
            }                      
        }
    }
}

}
The function is called from a userController.js on a express JS backend:
await sendEmail(mailOptions, successMessage, res, serviceSettings)
Node Version: 22.2.0
NPM Version: 10.7.0
Development Operating System: Windows 11
SMTP Server OS: Ubuntu 22.04 using Postfix and Dovecot
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
What have I done to mitigate this?

Changed from a self-hosted SMTP server (smtp.lumierelabs.org) to a gmail service. Same result. So it's not an SMTP problem.

Created a separate app aside from the project that has the nodemailer and still got the result.

Restarted computer. Same result.

Checked telnet of smtp.lumierelabs.org on Command Prompt, smtp server works. So I know it's not an SMTP problem.

Re-installed nodemailer

Googled the problem and can't find something similiar.

Turned off Windows Defender Firewall, no change.


